# Hibernate RX insert and flush and refresh return Exception when strategy is IDENTITY

Tags: hibernate, reactive-programming, hibernate-reactive

When I try hibernate rx library
and running the examples

```
        // obtain a reactive session
        factory.withTransaction(
                // persist the Authors with their Books in a transaction
                (session, tx) -> session.persist(author1, author2)
                        .flatMap(Mutiny.Session::flush)
                        .flatMap(s -> s.refresh())
        )
```

and

```
class Author {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;
```

it will throw CompletionException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [1] value by reflection : [class org.hibernate.example.reactive.Author.id] setter of org.hibernate.example.reactive.Author.id
```

I push test code in
https://github.com/semistone/hibernate-reactive/commit/398b1570666ed81a7d257020166f2ae59f1c5eb8

could someone help to check it.

Thanks

Comment: Try to create setter as it complained in the message of the exception: `public void setId(Integer val)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply
I add setter and getter and change type to Long
then it work

Comment: [link](https://github.com/semistone/hibernate-reactive/commit/f60864d6b7960bce2c54de6f7fef83f659b08524) `fix commit`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: [This is a bug](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/issues/609) and it will be fixed in Hibernate Reactive 1.0 CR1

The answer is in the comment but I will repeat it here.

You need to add a setter and change the id type to `Long` to make this work. The `Author` class becomes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="authors")
class Author {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull @Size(max=100)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = PERSIST)
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    Author(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Author() {}

    void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to add the flush operation (`.flatMap(Mutiny.Session::flush)`) because `withTransaction` already does that for you.

And you also don't need the `s.refresh`. Not sure why you would need it there.